# Move cursor position

Tags: vb.net, cursor, position, maskedtextbox

How to set the cursor position of a `MaskedTextBox` in VB.NET start from right? `MaskedTextBox` in my form is 5 digit numeric format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question.

```
    MaskedTextBox1.Focus()
    MaskedTextBox1.SelectionStart = 5
```

Answer (score 0):

Only this helped me:

```
private void TxtSeriesTxtNumber_EnterLeave(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            MaskedTextBox txt = sender as MaskedTextBox;
            if (txt.IsNull()) {
                return;
            }
            txt.Select(0, 0);
        }
```